# Cannot sort array into ascending numeric order in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array shown below using the `.sort()` method in JavaScript.

```
var addresses = [
    "5 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan",     
    "51 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan", 
    "53 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan", 
    "55 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan", 
    "57 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan", 
    "7 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan", 
    "9 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan"
];
```

However, after the `.sort` method has been invoked and I write the array to the document. The array doesn't seem to change into ascending numeric order.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Your array contains strings, so they'll be sorted alphabetically instead of  numerically. You'll want to use a sorting function as the parameter of array.sort and parse out the house number.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working in the end with the following code shown below:

```
function naturalCompare(a, b) {
    var ax = [], bx = [];

    a.replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function(_, $1, $2) { ax.push([$1 || Infinity, $2 || ""]) });
    b.replace(/(\d+)|(\D+)/g, function(_, $1, $2) { bx.push([$1 || Infinity, $2 || ""]) });

    while(ax.length && bx.length) {
        var an = ax.shift();
        var bn = bx.shift();
        var nn = (an[0] - bn[0]) || an[1].localeCompare(bn[1]);
        if(nn) return nn;
    }

    return ax.length - bx.length;
}

addresses = addresses.sort(naturalCompare);
```

Comment: `addresses = addresses.sort(naturalCompare);` is not needed. the sort method update the array, so you don't need to reassign `addresses`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this sort function that compare the first numbers of the strings

```js
var addresses = [
    "5 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan",     
    "51 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan", 
    "53 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan", 
    "55 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan", 
    "57 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan", 
    "7 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan", 
    "9 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan"
];


addresses.sort(function(a, b){
  return +a.split(" ")[0] - +b.split(" ")[0];
});

console.log(addresses);
```

Answer (score 0):

check below example

```
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var addresses = [
    "5 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan",     
    "51 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan", 
    "53 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan", 
    "55 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan", 
    "57 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan", 
    "7 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan", 
    "9 Glyn Eiddew, , , , Llanbradach, Caerphilly, Mid Glamorgan"
];

addresses.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.split(' ')[0] - b.split(' ')[0]
})
```